# Imagemagick depth convert

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick

Having an imgage `in.png`. Now do the next:

```
$ convert in.png -strip out.tiff     #convert to tiff
$ convert out.tiff -strip out.png    #and back
$ cmp in.png out.png
$#no output - the images has no difference - theyre same

$ identify in.png out.png
in.png PNG 300x300 300x300+0+0 16-bit sRGB 1.65KB 0.000u 0:00.000
out.png[1] PNG 300x300 300x300+0+0 16-bit sRGB 1.65KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

now trying this via `eps`. So:

```
$ convert in.png -strip out2.eps        #convert to eps
$ convert out2.eps -strip out2.png      #back
```

and the images are different.

```
$ identify in.png out.png out2.png
in.png PNG 300x300 300x300+0+0 16-bit sRGB 1.65KB 0.000u 0:00.000
out.png[1] PNG 300x300 300x300+0+0 16-bit sRGB 1.65KB 0.000u 0:00.000
out2.png[2] PNG 300x300 300x300+0+0 8-bit sRGB 4c 321B 0.000u 0:00.009
```

As you can see, the conversion eps -> png creates 8-bit png.

Curiosity plus - the EPS is 16 bit!

```
$ identify out2.eps 
out2.eps PS 300x300 300x300+0+0 16-bit sRGB 1.42KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Questions:

- why the `eps->png` conversion changes the bit-depth?
- how to convert from eps to png to get 16-bit png? (as from tiff).

## EDIT

Tested @Rachel recommendation:

```
$ convert out2.eps -depth 16 out3.png
$ identify out3.png 
out3.png PNG 300x300 300x300+0+0 8-bit sRGB 4c 518B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

8 bit again.

My ImageMagick version:

```
$ convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-1 Q16 x86_64 2014-06-01 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC Modules
Delegates: bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype gslib gvc jng jp2 jpeg lcms ltdl lzma pangocairo png ps tiff webp wmf x xml zlib
```

If anyone want test, here is my test image:

[image: test image]

## FINAL

So, @Mark Setchell and @Rachel Gallen's recommendation are good. @Marks command works, so the key is PNG48.

```
$ convert out2.eps -depth 16 PNG48:out7.png
$ identify out7.png
out7.png PNG 300x300 300x300+0+0 16-bit sRGB 1.86KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

**Finally** 16-bit png. What I will [ask it in another question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24685025/imagemagick-mogrify-strip-changes-image) why the next:

```
$ mogrify -strip out7.png
$ identify out7.png 
out7.png PNG 300x300 300x300+0+0 8-bit sRGB 4c 321B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

8 bit again. And the `-strip` should remove only metadata and should **not** change the image itself.

Comment: you didn't put in the PNG16: option

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you need something along these lines to get 16-bit PNGs

```
convert a.png -depth 16 PNG48:b.png
```

Comment: So sould convert first `eps->png` (get 8bit) and convert again from 8bit png to 16 bit png? thats doesn't mean loss at `eps->png`?

Comment: I was just illustrating the concept really, of generating a 16 (or 48-bit) PNG. I presume you could put those parameters and switches directly onto the EPS->PNG conversion.

Comment: OK - going to test again

Answer (score 2):

i think from looking at the [docs](http://bullard.esc.cam.ac.uk/~taylor/Doc/imagemagick/docs/ImageMagick.pdf) you can do

```
   convert -depth 16 image.eps image2.png[16]
```

the syntax is

```
   convert [ options … ] file [file …] file
```

[This site](http://archive.ncsa.illinois.edu/Cyberia/stats/ImageMagick/www/convert.html) says 'Use an optional index enclosed in brackets after a file name to specify a desired subimage of a multi-resolution image format like Photo CD (e.g. img0001.pcd[4]) or a range for MPEG images (e.g. video.mpg[50-75]).'

so maybe put the [16] after image2.png

Comment: It created a file with name: `PNG16:out6.png` and the identify prints: `PNG16:out6.png PNG 300x300 300x300+0+0 8-bit sRGB 4c 518B 0.000u 0:00.000`. Something is wrong with my ImageMagick?

Comment: :) yes, trying many variants a hour long and didn't get anythig good.

Comment: According to https://sites.google.com/site/scientificsimulation/other-software/imagemagick 16-bit pngs are not supportedin imagemagick!!!

Comment: hm.. but conversion from a tiff file works - see the 1st example.

Comment: @jm666 curious. why do you need it to be 16bit? out of curiosity?

Comment: I'm not sure. ;) Simply, when converting to 8bit I didn't lose some informations? Espacially when the original (input) is 16bit?

Comment: Good point - the solution was instead PNG16 need to use PNG48 and @Mark recommended. Thank you. ;)