# Imagemagick "mogrify -strip" - changes image?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

In my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24683912/imagemagick-depth-convert) asked about the conversions and bit depth:

So, doing this:

```
$ convert in.png out.eps
$ convert out.eps out.png
$ identify in.png out.eps out.png
in.png PNG 300x300 300x300+0+0 16-bit sRGB 1.65KB 0.000u 0:00.000
out.eps[1] PS 300x300 300x300+0+0 16-bit sRGB 1.42KB 0.000u 0:00.009
out.png[2] PNG 300x300 300x300+0+0 8-bit sRGB 4c 518B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

So, wrong depth. The input image is 16 bit. The `eps` is 16bit. The output png (from eps) is 8bit.

Based on answer, tried the next:

```
$ convert out.eps -depth 16 PNG48:out2.png
$ identify out2.png 
out2.png PNG 300x300 300x300+0+0 16-bit sRGB 1.86KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Got 16 bit png. Great.

Now stripping the metadata.

```
$ mogrify -strip out2.png 
$ identify out2.png 
out2.png PNG 300x300 300x300+0+0 8-bit sRGB 4c 321B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Question: **Why** the `-strip` changes the image format? It should only strip the metadata. Or no?

When `-strip` the original image:

```
$ mogrify -strip in.png 
$ identify in.png 
in.png PNG 300x300 300x300+0+0 16-bit sRGB 1.65KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

The image format is not changed.

Another strange things are the image sizes. The stripped original image:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 jm  staff    1645 10 júl 21:49 in.png
```

The stripped converted image has only:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 jm  staff     321 10 júl 21:45 out2.png
```

So, something is wrong somewhere. Maybe in the conversion or with the mogrify... or.. don;t know. ;(

Comment: Hi, sorry late but : identify look at metadata : 16bit. Remove the metadata : look at real bits : 8bits ? verbose : http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#verbose can surely help